# How can I change listBoxSelecteditem with keyUP and keyDown?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change listBoxselectedItem.But I only change with mouse click.I want to change with keyup and keydown.please if you know can you help me?

Comment: @HighCore what is the connection to the question?@Emre Tan please write your code an explain your question.....maybe code....

Comment: I don't find code about this problem

Comment: What is the problem????

Comment: @OneManCrew First of all this is not a question. At least not in the form expected in SO. Once the OP reads thru the post I linked to he'll (hopefully) post an actual question.

Comment: I understand that  @HighCore is new here....we need to help hem to write his question right.....and (hopefully) to answer it.

Comment: How can I change listBoxSelecteditem with keyUP and keyDown?I want to code why don't you understat me?

Comment: @HighCore you your props is to keyUP and keyDown events?

Comment: @EmreTan Post your XAML. I tried a vanilla ListBox in WPF and it already supports moving selected item with up and down keys (WPF 4.0)

Comment: try this on keyDown Event:   private void listBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key==Key.Up)
            {
                listBox.SelectedIndex++;
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                listBox.SelectedIndex--;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. You have to be aware that the ListBox starts with Index 0 if you press key down you have to increment the .SelectedIndex so you select the Item with Index 1

```
            //Key Up
        if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Up && (listBox.SelectedIndex - 1) > -1)
        {
            listBox.SelectedIndex--;
        }

        //Key Down
        if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Down && (listBox.SelectedIndex + 1) < listBox.Items.Count)
        {
            listBox.SelectedIndex++;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

**try this on keyDown Event:**

```
private void listBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Key==Key.Up && listBox.SelectedIndex+1<listBox.Items.Count) 
    { 

        listBox.SelectedIndex++; 
    } 
     if (e.Key == Key.Down && listBox.SelectedIndex-1<-1) 
     { 
         listBox.SelectedIndex--; 
     } 
}
```

Comment: If you set selected index then you resemple the SelectionMode="Single" as you do not permit the user to select more than one with the arrow keys. But if indeed SelectionMode="Single" then nothing is needed

Comment: May be this line if (e.Key == Key.Down && listBox.SelectedIndex-1<-1) should be if (e.Key == Key.Down && listBox.SelectedIndex-1>-1)